# scrollview with multiple UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, scrollview

I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement multiple UIViewControllers within a UIScrollView. For now, I initiate my UIViewController manually and add it as a Subview to Scrollview. This works fine, but the scrollview doesn't show more than ONE UIViewController even after scrolling to the right. Any idea why this might happen? Here's my code:

```
DTArticle *article = [self.articles objectAtIndex:0];
DTArticle *article2 = [self.articles objectAtIndex:1];
UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
DTArticleViewController *controller = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DTArticleViewController"];
DTArticleViewController *controller2 = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DTArticleViewController"];
controller.article = article;
controller2.article = article2;    

[self.parentScrollView addSubview:controller.view];
[self.parentScrollView addSubview:controller2.view];
self.parentScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.parentScrollView.frame.size.width
                                               * 2, self.parentScrollView.frame.size.height);
self.parentScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
[self.parentScrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[self.view addSubview:self.parentScrollView];
```

Comment: Have you considered using UIPageViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you've added, both views are at the same location, one on top of the other. When you add the second view you should change its frame origin to position it next to the first view.